# GRIDDB: Cannot perform database backup using gs_backup command

Tags: backup, griddb

I have setup a GRIDDB environment on CentOS 7. So far the service is running fine on the OS, but when I tried to take a database backup using gs_backup command it returned follwing error.

$ gs_backup -u admin/admin 20141025
bash: gs_backup: command not found...

Searching on my CentOS host, I could not find any gs_backup.

$ gs_
gs_adduser       gs_deluser       gs_joincluster   gs_leavecluster  gs_passwd        gs_sh            gs_startnode     gs_stat          gs_stopcluster   gs_stopnode

I tired to search for some solution but still unable to find one. Please help in this regards.

Thanks